# plot time series with pandas ATTRIBUTE ERROR

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am having a problem with plotting a data frame. The data frame looks like this:

```
                     0              1
0  2012-01-01 00:00:00  123900.776741
1  2012-01-01 00:00:05  123900.776741
2  2012-01-01 00:00:10  123900.776741
3  2012-01-01 00:00:15  123900.776741
4  2012-01-01 00:00:20  123900.776741
5  2012-01-01 00:00:25  124815.050322
6  2012-01-01 00:00:30  125702.149798
7  2012-01-01 00:00:35  126589.249274
8  2012-01-01 00:00:40  127476.348751
9  2012-01-01 00:00:45  128363.448227
```

Notice that the time goes up in increments of 5 seconds.

When I write:

```
for x in monitor1:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(x, header=None, comment='#'))
df=pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])

#dates=pd.date_range('2012-01-01', '2012-02-01', freq='5S')
#dates=dates[:-1]
df.columns = ['Time', 'Data']
df = df.set_index('Time')
plt.plot(df)
```

I get this:
AttributeError: 'TimeSeriesFigure' object has no attribute '_seen'

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's because your column with the time is not the index.

Assuming the exact same dataframe, try the following :

```
# Renaming the columns for more clarity
df.columns = ['Time', 'Data']
# setting Time as index
df = df.set_index('Time')
# Plotting
df['Data'].plot()
```

Comment: Please post what code you used exactly and your error

Comment: The problem is that the type of the index is pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex. This is incompatible with numpy >1.7 apparently. The error I get is 'TimeSeriesFigure' object has no attribute '_seen'.

Comment: updated my code, if you have a chance it would be great if you could review